# Code logic for "don't require OTP for this device"?

Tags: totp

I've just implemented QR-based TOTP on a web site. Immediately I have people (quite reasonably, given the application) asking for a checkbox so the site doesn't require TOTP for that computer and browser for some amount of time. (Probably will be 8 hours....)

What is the most secure way to apply this? Somehow just plopping down a cookie in their browser seems insecure -- somebody managing to see that cookie can totally bypass the TOTP system.

This website uses the general Session timeout of 20 minutes.

So what is the best secure workflow for recording this preference? I've thought of a setting saved in the DB for that user -- store their IP address and a timestamp? Combine that with the cookie? Is there a standard way to do this that works well?

Comment: How does the website remember they are logged in, or do they have to enter a TOTP every time they load a page?

Comment: Session variable, but that disappears after 20 minutes

Comment: What is a session variable?

Comment: It's basically a cookie with an I.D., with a matching value (and some data) stored on the server

Comment: and why is that secure?

Comment: I don't precisely know.  Making session variables leverages the expertise of the people who designed the language you're using. I just set Session and it's done. I don't know what exactly is done to it to secure it.  That isn't the same when you're creating a cookie from scratch.  That's why I'm asking the question: I don't want to, in my ignorance, leave my system wide open.

Comment: Lacking a better answer, I'll be using the "Proactively Secure Long-Term User Authentication" method from this page: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the flag on the client side, e.g. in a cookie, you can either encrypt the cookie or create HMAC using server side secret. The user will not be able to manipulate it. Put to this cookie timestamp when the flag was set. Thus old cookies cannot be reused later on. Set also proper expiration time, so that browser does not delete it too early.

You can use also local storage in browser.